# How to make a RegEx fit in Python

Tags: python, regex

My end goal is to be able to pull the word or words out of the quotes after `title="`.  I have a text file with a bunch of long lines of HTML and each line has a `title="some place"` in it towards the end.  I have a regex that I'm still trying to get 100% dialed in but, for now, looks something like this:

```
(?=(title=\")$)(.+?)
```

No, it doesn't work quite yet but I think I can get that taken care of.  I have another one though that does work but it pulls out the entire `title="thing"` and if it's got more than one word in quotes, it lops the end off:

`title="some`

The problem that I'm running into at this point is that I can't figure out how to get it IN my script.  I can have the most ep1c l33t h@x0r regex known to man but it's useless if I can't get it into my script.  It has so many parenthesizes, quotes and whatnot that Python recognizes that I don't know how to "slash-out" everything properly to make it work.

If I could get a bit of guidance regarding keeping the Python interpreter happy in this case, I'd appreciate it.

And, if there's a regex master out there that can help button up the regex itself, I'd appreciate that as well.

Thanks for your help and if you have any questions or need clarification, (I tried to be a clear as possible!  lol) please let me know!

Thanks!

Thanks for the `r'...` comment!  That seems to have gotten it into Python correctly.  Saw that a while back too and forgot all about it.  Noted.  lol

As for a piece of the html, it's a page I've scraped down and stripped all the lines I want using BeautifulSoup.  Here's a piece of one of the lines:

`<td style="background-color:red;width...false;"weight:bold;height:8px;;margin:0px;background:none" title="some thing" type="button" value="PCL"/>`

Here's a "censored" copy of the entire code as it sits right now.  It works perfectly with BeautifulSoup except it only returns the `title` info for the first line.

```
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print "What do you want to call the file?"
filename = raw_input()
print "Ok, it's %r." % filename

print "Opening %r..." % filename
target = open(filename, 'w')

sock = urllib.urlopen("http://1.1.1.1.censored.company.url")
htmlSource = sock.read()
sock.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)

tables = soup.find_all('tr')

print "Writing file..."
target.write(str(tables))

print "Now it's time to extract what we want."
data = open(filename, "r")
found = open("Found.txt", "w")

for line in data:
    if re.match("(.*)(background-color:red)(.*)", line):
        print >> found, line,

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("Found.txt"))
parts = open("Out.txt", "w")

tag = soup.input

value_I_want = tag['title']

parts.write(value_I_want)
```

Comment: A string prefixed with an r (outside the quotes) is interpreted as a "raw" string. E.g. `r'these\backslashes\are\totally\literal'`

Comment: How about actually showing us the regex you're trying to put in your script?

Comment: `matches = re.findall(\"(.+?)\",text)` is what I have in the script right now that _sorta_ works.

Comment: Have you considered using a parser?

Comment: do you know the text you're looking for will always be in double quotes and not single ?

Comment: @hwnd - No sir.  Pretty new to this whole Python thing still...

Comment: @hwnd - It's actually in a '<input id=` tag.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to do the regex "word(s) out of double quotes that immediately follow `title=` is because I know that it's the only instance of `title=` and I know it will always be there.

Comment: Can you post an example, you can use beautifulsoup to do this.

Comment: Well, I am just wondering if `title="something"` is actually just contained in the `<input ...>` tag or other tags?

Comment: Oh oh.  Got ya.  Yes, it's in the `<input ...>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using `BeautifulSoup` you said, why not use that to extract your attributes?

```
>>> matches = [x['title'] for x in soup.find_all('input')]
```

**Example**: ( Going off your comment that the title attributes are inside `input` tags )

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''<input id="foo" title="something">
<input id="foo" title="something else">
<input id="foo" title="something again">'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> matches = [x['title'] for x in soup.find_all('input')]
>>> matches
['something', 'something else', 'something again']
```

**Edit**: To print each result on a separate line:

```
>>> for tag in soup.find_all('input'):
...     print tag['title']
```

Comment: You, my friend, win the gold star.  Dunno why this got pushed to the bottom.  I didn't even see it!!

All the results are there as they should be.  Only thing now, how can I get each result on its own line?  It's just a big blob of names now.  lol  DEFINITELY a step in the right direction though!

You rock, man!!

Comment: @rmp5s You can use, `for x in matches: print x` or see updated edit.

Comment: Perfect.  It is now 100%.  Thanks everyone for the assistance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using BeautifulSoup, then you don't need a regular expression at all! Just put the element that BeautifulSoup returns into a variable (I'll use `td` in my example) and then do:

```
value_I_want = td['title']
```

BeautifulSoup has already done the parsing for you. See [this part of the BeautifulSoup docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) for how to retrieve attributes. Then read the rest of the page to see what else you can get from BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Using `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tds = open("line.txt", "r")

value_I_want = td['title']`

...I'm getting `TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.  

Did I mention I'm a bit of a n00b?  :-P

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @rmp5s - You said, "As for a piece of the html, it's a page I've scraped down and stripped all the lines I want using BeautifulSoup." Could you post the code you use to do that? The best way would be to use that code, and instead of writing the line out to a `line.txt` file, instead use my suggestion in the appropriate place. But I can't tell you exactly where to place it without seeing your code. Post the code you use to get that `line.txt` file, and then I should be able to help you.

Comment: Well...I've mostly gotten it working.

It only reads the top line...how can I get it read the rest of the 300+ lines of HTML?